# How to compute many sums or tables efficiently

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, special-functions, summation

I have some questions about programming in Mathematica and I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

I wish to plot the following function against the variable X, but to do this, first I have to solve the problem of how to perform 10 sums on different indexes efficiently, that is, in the shortest time possible. I have also tried to do with Tables or Matrices, but I have not been able to achieve a result, possibly I still need to learn more about how to apply them. Thank you very much.

```
FUN1[X_?NumericQ] := Parallelize[Sum[(-1)^(K2 - M1 - M2) I^(P1 + P2) 
   (2 P1 + 1) (2 P2 + 1)Sqrt[((2 L1 + 1) (2 L2 + 1))/((2 Λ1 +1) (2 Λ2 + 1))] 
   SphericalBesselJ[P1, -M1*140*X] SphericalBesselJ[P2, -M2*140*X] 
   SphericalHarmonicY[L1, -M1, Pi/2, 0] SphericalHarmonicY[L2, -M2, Pi/2, 0] 
   ClebschGordan[{70, 70}, {L1, 0}, {70, 70}] 
   ClebschGordan[{70, 70}, {L2, 0}, {70, 70}] 
   ClebschGordan[{P1, 0}, {L1, 0}, {Λ1, 0}] 
   ClebschGordan[{P2, 0}, {L2, 0}, {Λ2, 0}] 
   ClebschGordan[{P1, 0}, {L1, M1}, {Λ1, K1}] 
   ClebschGordan[{P2, 0}, {L2, M2}, {Λ2, K2}] 
   KroneckerDelta[Λ1, Λ2] KroneckerDelta[-K1, K2], 
 {L1, 0, 140}, {M1, -L1, L1}, {P1, 0, 280},
 {Λ1, Abs[P1 - L1], P1 + L1}, {K1, -Λ1, Λ1}, 
 {L2, 0,  140}, {M2, -L2, L2}, {P2, 0, 280},
 {Λ2, Abs[P2 - L2], P2 + L2}, {K2, -Λ2, Λ2}
 ]
]
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume when you have `KroneckerDelta[\[CapitalLambda]1, \[CapitalLambda]2] \KroneckerDelta[-K1, K2]` you are actually trying to divide them?  If so then the \ between the `KroneckerDelta` s needs to be a /.

Comment: Hello, @That Gravity Guy. No, sorry,  it's just the product of KroneckerDelta(Lambda1,Lambda2)*KroneckerDelta(-K1,K2).  I already corrected it, thanks.

Comment: There's also `ParallelSum` which is effectively the same as what you have `Parallelize@Sum`, just to clean it up a little.

Comment: Thank you, @That Gravity Guy.

Answer (score 9):

Just to give you an idea what you try to do:

The number of summands in your sum is

```
m = Sum[(2 Λ1 + 1) (2 L1 + 1), {L1, 0, 140}, {P1, 0, 280}, {Λ1, Abs[P1 - L1], P1 + L1}];
numberOfSummands = N[m^2]
```

> 8.70977*10^22

Your summands contain special functions such as `ClebschGordan`, `SphericalBesselJ`, and `SphericalHarmonicY`, functions that need many floating point operations per evaluation. Let's be very conservative and say that each of these functions needs 10 floating point operations, which makes about 100 floating point operations per summand. So, it is a very, very conservative lower bound to say that we have to perform this many floating point operations in total

```
floatOpsNeeded = numberOfSummands 100
```

> 8.70977*10^24

The [most powerful computer on earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOP500#Top_500_ranking) is currently (at the time I write this) [Summit]https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summit_(Supercomputer) with 122.3 PFLOPS; that's `1.223 10^17` floating point operations per second. Let's assume that you can perfectly parallelize your code on Summit so that you get really the full 122.3 PFLOPS. Then you would need this many seconds:

```
SummitPower = 1.223 10^17;
sec = floatOpsNeeded/SummitPower
```

> 7.12164*10^7

And in days, this is

```
sec/60/60/24
```

> 824.264

That's more than two years on the fastest computer on earth! So your question should rather not be about how to sum efficiently. It should be on how to simplify or to approximate the sum in a way that cuts down the number of floating point operations *by several orders of magnitude*.

A first step towards that would be to use the `KroneckerDelta`s to eliminate the summations over `Λ2` and `K2`. Then at least *Summit* would be able to compute the sum in about 22 seconds:

```
m1 = Sum[(2 Λ1 + 1) (2 L1 + 1), {L1, 0, 140}, {P1, 0, 280}, {Λ1, Abs[P1 - L1], P1 + L1}];
m2 = Sum[(2 L1 + 1), {L1, 0, 140}, {P1, 0, 280}];
m1 m2 100/SummitPower/60
```

> 22.4683

But this is only the evaluation time of `FUN1[X]` for a single `X` and it is not easy to get computation time on such large clusters. So quite certainly, you have to simplify the summation even more.

**Edit:**

The summands appear to be symmetric in the index pairs `{P1, P2}`, `{M1, M2}`,  and `{L1, L2}`. At least the summetry in `{P1, P2}` and `{L1, L2}` is easily exploited and would reduce the number of summands to compute by roughly a factor of 4 (by summing only `P1<P2` and `L1<L2` and multiplying by `4` and by addong the sum for `P1 == P2` and `L1 == L2`). If the symmetry in `{M1, M2}` could also be exploited, this would be a nother factor of 2. And so on...

**Edit 2:**

The way physicists expand their summations is far from optimal from the point of view of numerics -- not only because of their extensive usage of Kronecker deltas. (This is meant non-judgemental: The *theoretical* work with nested sums is often simplified significantly this way.) Roughly, your sum has the form

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m a_{i,k} \, b_{j,k}.$$

The brute-force summation would need $m \, n^2$ multiply and add operations (modern machines use fused multiply-add operations when appropriately vectorizing the code but that is not essential in the following).

The resulting number will be equal to

$$\sum_{k=1}^m  \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i,k}\right) \, \left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_{i,k} \right).$$

Performing the summations in parentheses *first* requires $2 n$ summations. *Afterwards*, the outer sum requires $m$ multipilations and $m$ additions. Hence this approach would cut the effort from $m \, n^2$ multiplications and $m \, n^2$ addtions to only $m$ multiplications and $2 n + m$ additions.

With your actual `n` and `m`, we have

```
n = Sum[(2 L1 + 1), {L1, 0, 140}, {P1, 0, 280}]
m = (140 + 280)^2
Dataset@<|
  "First" -> <|"Multiplications" -> m n^2, "Additions" -> m n^2|>,
  "Second" -> <|"Multiplications" -> m, "Additions" -> 2 n + m|>
  |>
```

**Edit 3:**

The Clebsch-Gordan symbols

```
ClebschGordan[{P1, 0}, {L1, M1}, {Λ1, K1}]
```

vanishes if `M1 != K1`. That means that the product

```
Times[
 ClebschGordan[{P1, 0}, {L1, M1}, {Λ1, K1}], 
 ClebschGordan[{P2, 0}, {L2, M2}, {Λ2, K2}],
 KroneckerDelta[Λ1, Λ2], 
 KroneckerDelta[-K1, K2]
]
```

is nonvanishing only if `M1 == K1 == -K2 == - M2` and `Λ1 == Λ2`. That gets you rid of four(!) summation variables.

All in all, this should give you plenty of ideas how to compute the sum significantly faster.

Comment: Thank you very much,@Henrik Schumacher. I will consider your advice.

Comment: One last question, @Henrik Shumacher. If I program correctly with matrices or tables, do you think that the time to obtain results would not be greatly reduced?. Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed, using matrices and `Dot` can speed up many computations. The problem that I see here is with memory: You simply have not enough memory to  store all summands. But storing _some_ intermediate results in arrays so that they need not be recomputed, may speed up the computation.

Comment: Btw.: What are the typical values if `X`? I always get error messages of the form `"blablabla is not physical."` (error message `ClebschGordan::phy`).

Comment: X can be any real number greater than or equal to zero. The message ClebschGordan::phy  is because non-physical coefficients are evaluated, but Mathematica gives them the value zero automatically.

Comment: Ah, so evaluating `Off[ClebschGordan::phy]` in the beginning will greatly speed up the evaluation.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, @Henrik Schumacher.